# Retrieving JSON data in PHP called using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to get the value from $data->username but it returns NULL because input is not json. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my current code.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                url: 'http://penguin.linux.test/api/login.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });

    });
```

PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input", true));
}
```

Comment: just use 'JSON' in dataType key instead of 'application/json'

Comment: PHP can just read the variables from $_POST in the normal way. `.serialize()` will send the data in normal form-url-encoded format. No need for anything JSON-related

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAkram true but it's irrelevant to the issue because that setting controls how jQuery processes the response, not how it sends the request

Comment: What is best practice today? Run it as form-url-encoded format or JSON? Raw php://input or $_POST?

Comment: There's no such thing as "best" overall. Both can be useful at different times. Use whatever is most suitable for your situation. Sometimes JSON will be advantageous because you can often represent a more complex data structure. Or form data can be good because it requires less work to use it. You just need to decide what you want.